# Trying to get a regular expression to work in the workflow rule formula editor

Tags: workflow, formula, regular-expressions

I'm trying determine the shipper from the tracking number using regex in a workflow rule formula. Similar too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619977/regular-expression-patterns-for-tracking-numbers

except when I escape the "/" for the editor the regex fails to match... so I'm kinda stuck.

Here is my original regex:

`/\b(1Z ?[0-9A-Z]{3} ?[0-9A-Z]{3} ?[0-9A-Z]{2} ?[0-9A-Z]{4} ?[0-9A-Z]{3} ?[0-9A-Z]|[\dT]\d\d\d ?\d\d\d\d ?\d\d\d)\b/i`

Here is my formula from the editor

```
IF(REGEX(Tracking_Number__c, '/\\b(1Z ?[0-9A-Z]{3} ?[0-9A-Z]{3} ?[0-9A-Z]{2} ?[0-9A-Z]{4} ?[0-9A-Z]{3} ?[0-9A-Z]|[\\dT]\\d\\d\\d ?\\d\\d\\d\\d ?\\d\\d\\d)\\b/i'), "http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/processInputRequest?HTMLVersion<br>=5.0&sort_by=status&loc=en_US&InquiryNumber1="+ Tracking_Number__c, "")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't wrap your expressions in forward slashes (`/`), it's not Javascript! If you want to make your expression case-insensitive, begin it with the case-insensitive flag: `(?i)`. Also, last I checked, `Workflow Rules` do not support `REGEX`, so you might have to move your logic to `Process Builder`.

Comment: Salesforce has documentation on regex which seems to elude that it can be used in formulas. https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008vYrIAI. I wrapped it as such as since I had read: "Regular expression syntax is based on Java Platform SE 6 syntax. However, backslash characters (\) must be changed to double backslashes (\\) because backslash is an escape character in Salesforce.".

However, you may be right. I have a case with Salesforce right now so I'll follow up with their input.

Thanks

Comment: You were right about the "/"'s. However the formula fields do support regex. Be weary of the support. As they had passed this case along to different reps one told me they wouldn't support it and tried to close my case. Another rep was very helpful.

Comment: So basically my answer did resolve your issue? @user1040975

Comment: In a manner of speaking, sure. I'll give it to ya. I'd just given you a bump, but I can't yet.

Answer (score 0):

It was a syntax issue:

```
\\b(1Z ?[0-9A-Z]{3} ?[0-9A-Z]{3} ?[0-9A-Z]{2} ?[0-9A-Z]{4} ?[0-9A-Z]{3} ?[0-9A-Z]|[\\dT]\\d\\d\\d ?\\d\\d\\d\\d ?\\d\\d\\d)\\b
```

took out all the "/"'s and the case group. 
works.